# Invoking a method via reflection with generics and overrides

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, overriding

I'm trying to invoke the RegisterType method in the Unity container. RegisterType has a total of 16 overrides (some of those are parameters some are types).

I'm trying to perform the equivalent of:

```
Container.RegisterType<IMyDataProvider, MockData.MockProvider>("MockData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

Using GetMethod() was a total failure, so I ended up doing this ugly thing:

```
     MethodInfo registerTypeGeneric = Container.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
        Where(p => p.ToString() == "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer RegisterType[TFrom,TTo](System.String, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.LifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])").FirstOrDefault();
     MethodInfo registerTypeSpecific = registerTypeGeneric.MakeGenericMethod( new Type[] { typeof(IMyDataProvider), Assembly.LoadFrom("MockData.dll").GetType("MockData.MockProvider") });
     registerTypeSpecific.Invoke(Container, new object[] { "MockData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() });
```

And this works beautifully, up until the Invoke which complains because I have no InjectionMember parameters (they're optional and I don't have any to give). So, according to the documentation, I have to use Type.InvokeMember() to call a method with optional parameters.

So I did this:

```
     Binder binder = new BootstrapperBinder();
     Container.GetType().InvokeMember("RegisterType",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        binder,
        Container,
        new object[] { "MockData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() });
```

My BoostrapperBinder class does this:

```
  public override MethodBase BindToMethod(BindingFlags bindingAttr, MethodBase[] match, ref object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, string[] names, out object state)
  {
     Type mockProvider = Assembly.LoadFrom("MockData.dll").GetType("MockData.MockProvider");
     state = new object();
     MethodInfo mi = Container.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
        Where(p => p.ToString() == "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer RegisterType[TFrom,TTo](System.String, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.LifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])").FirstOrDefault();
     return mi.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(ICarrierApprovalDataChangeAccessorEndPoint), mockProvider });
  }
```

Yes, it's ugly, but I just use it for this oen case, so it does the job.

Now, the problem is, it's still complaining about the lack of a third parameter. I can't pass null or Missing.Value either, or it croaks. I've tried with and without BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding. I'm stumped.

(Edited to put the Container.RegisterType example in code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial post mentioned that I had tried passing null as a 3rd parameter and that the app "croaked." Specifically, it was getting a null reference exception and I should have been more clear about that.

The solution was to pass "new InjectionMember[0]" instead of null, so the Invoke() should have looked like this:

```
registerTypeSpecific.Invoke(Container, new object[] { "MockData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[0] });
```

Thanks to Jason for his help. His sample sent me down the path that eventually led to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't pass `null` or`Missing.Value` either, or it croaks.

Croaks how? You **should** be able to pass `null` for a `params` parameter (when you invoke a method like `M(params object[] objects)` via `M()` it will be the case that `objects` is null within the method.

Second, you can lookup the method more cleanly. I don't have a compiler at my fingertips, but try this:

```
var registerTypeMethodInfo = 
     typeof(IUnityContainer).GetMethods()
                            .Where(m => m.Name == "RegisterType")
                            .Where(m => m.GetParameters()
                                 .Select(p => p.ParameterType)
                                 .SequenceEqual(new[] {
                                      typeof(string), 
                                      typeof(LifetimeManager),
                                      typeof(InjectionMember[])
                                 })
                            )
                            .Where(m => m.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2)
                            .SingleOrDefault();
Assert.NotNull(registerTypeMethodInfo);
var methodInfo = 
    registerTypeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] {
        typeof(IMyDataProvider), 
        typeof(MockData.MockProvider)
    });
```

Then invoke the method like so, passing `null` for the `params InjectionMember[]` parameter:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(
    Container,
    new object[] { 
        "MockData",
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        null
    }
);
```

Sorry if it doesn't compile. If it doesn't compile, this will get you very close to a correct solution.

Here is a self-contained example that works:

```
namespace ParamsTest {
    interface Foo {
        void M<T>(string s, int n, params object[] objects);
    }
    class Bar : Foo {
        public void M<T>(string s, int n, params object[] objects) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.WriteLine(objects == null);
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
        }
    }
    internal class Program {
        internal static void Main(string[] args) {
            var genericMethodInfo =
                typeof(Foo).GetMethods()
                    .Where(m => m.Name == "M")
                    .Where(m => m.GetParameters()
                       .Select(p => p.ParameterType)
                       .SequenceEqual(new[] {
                           typeof(string),
                           typeof(int),
                           typeof(object[])
                       })
                    )
                    .Where(m => m.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 1)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
            var methodInfo =
                genericMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(
                    new[] { typeof(DateTime) }
                );
            var bar = new Bar();
            methodInfo.Invoke(bar, new object[] { "Hello, world!", 17, null });
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Hello, world!
17
True
DateTime
```

on the console.

> I've tried with and without BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding. I'm stumped.

`params` is not part of the signature of a method. It is a compiler trick to allow variable-length parameter lists. `BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding` is for binding optional parameters to their default values.

Comment: The LINQ in the GetMethods fails due to more than one return (it has 16 overrides, some of them are with different generic type parameters), but if I use my way to get the methodinfo, the Invoke still fails with a null reference exception in the RegisterType() method. Since Container is not null, I can only assume the null parameter is the cause.

Comment: That's easy to fix. Add a `.Where(m => m.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2)` before the call to `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: As for the problem you are experiencing with `null`, try invoking the method through a static method invocation (i.e., strip away the reflection). Just call `Container.RegisterType<IMyDataProvider, MockData.MockProvider>("MockData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), null)` and see if you get the same problem. If you do, the problem is NOT the dynamic invocation and instead it is something else (maybe the way that you set up the container?).

Comment: `Container.RegisterType<IMyDataProvider, MockData.MockProvider>("MockData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())` works fine `Container.RegisterType<IMyDataProvider, MockData.MockProvider>("MockData", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), null)` throws a null reference exception. I doubt it has anything to do with how the container is set up. If the two are equivalent to the runtime, then I would think they should act identically.

Comment: The only code related to the container called prior to the RegisterType calls above was `UnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer()`. So I think that rules out container set up issues.

Comment: If you take your sample and replace the reflection with `new Bar().M<DateTime>("Hello, world!", 17)`, I think you'll see why null doesn't work and hence, the solution to my problem.