# Call MethodInfo.Invoke on Method with genericArguments

Tags: c#, reflection

I get an `InvalidOperation` Exception when calling `MethodInfo.Invoke` on my Method, its because it has generic Arguments. After hours of searching in Internet I don't know how to solve this problem. Here is the `MethodInfo`:

```
object value = null;
if (propertyType.IsClass)
{
    Type primaryKeyType = propertyType.GetPrimaryKeyType();
    object primaryKeyValue = property.Value.ToValue(primaryKeyType);
    MethodInfo GetEntityMethodInfo = typeof(ReportSettingsExtensions)
        .GetMethod("GetEntity", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object entity = propertyType;
    GetEntityMethodInfo.Invoke(entity, new object[] { primaryKeyValue });
    value = entity.GetPrimaryKey();
}
```

And here is the method:

```
private static T GetEntity<T>(object primaryKeyValue)
{
    T entity = default(T);
    new Storage(storage =>
    {
        entity = storage.Create<T>();
        entity.SetPrimaryKey(primaryKeyValue);
        storage.Load(entity);
    });

    return entity;
}
```

Comment: I once asked a similar question and got a good answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333896/invoking-a-method-via-reflection-with-generics-and-overrides

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide or "close" the generic method parameter `T`, using `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` ( [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) )

Something like this:

```
MethodInfo getEntity =
  GetEntityMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod( ... whatever T should be ... );

var entity = getEntity.Invoke( null, new object[] { primaryKeyValue } );
```

You should pass `null` as the first parameter to `Invoke` because the method is `static` and so doesn't have an object reference.

Comment: It still doesnt work completely but this answer helped a lot, thanks!